# What hook to alter the result of a view?

Tags: views, 8

In a custom module, I have a custom entity for which a view shows the following values:

[image: screenshot]

*Contact* is the ID of another entity (Person) containing some fields, such as *Email*. *Adresse courriel* is a *Custom text* field defined in the view.

What hook should I use to achieve the following task?

1. Query the *Person* entity with the *Contact* value to retrieve the *Email* field value
2. Update *Adresse courriel* in the view output

Comment: Please refer UserViewsData or other subclass of EntityViewsData class for a reference how to achieve such.

Comment: Why don't you use relationship in views?

Comment: @usmanjutt84 I tried. But I couldn't find how to link my content to Person entity. The entity on which my view is based (ContractSubscription) is linked to Member entity. So I could add Member entity to the View with 'Relation' feature and then I can dispaly Désignation and Contact fields. But from here, I could'n( find a way to add Person entity: it doesn't appear in the entities list of 'Relation'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to `MemberViewsData.php`:

```
class MemberViewsData extends EntityViewsData
{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getViewsData()
  {
    $data = parent::getViewsData();

    // Additional information for Views integration, such as table joins, can be
    // put here.
    $data['member']['contact_id'] = array(
      'title' => t('Contact Id'),
      'relationship' => array(
        'base' => 'person',
        'base field' => 'id',
        'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
        'label' => t('Member to Person (Contact)'),
        'title' => t('Person (Contact)'),
        'id' => 'standard',
      ),
    );
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Then I could use Views UI, adding a 'Relation' from Member (main entity of my view) to Person. And here it is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1- Firstly you need to add a relationship to the Person entity to have the fields available.

2- then use `hook_views_query_alter()` to change the fields values.